# How to read sms from specific card sim dual sim phone

Tags: android-studio, sms

I' trying to read all inbox sms the code below work fine,but with dual sim phone only the first sim sms appear there is any solution to get the 2 sims sms

```
var msgs = mutableListOf<JSONObject>()
        var msg = ""
        val uriSms: Uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")
        val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
            uriSms,
            arrayOf("_id", "address", "date", "body"),
            null,
            null,
            null
        )

        cursor?.moveToFirst()
        while (cursor?.moveToNext() == true) {
            var msgJson = JSONObject()
            val address: String = cursor.getString(1)
            val body: String = cursor.getString(3)
            val date: String = cursor.getString(2)
            msgJson.put("mobile_number", address)
            msgJson.put("body", body)
            msgJson.put("date", date)
            msgs.add(msgJson)
        }
```

Comment: Hi Aymen, a language tag would help!

Comment: Thanks for repley Is my question clear now ?